# Convert short/dos style path name to full path name

Tags: c++, qt

The title says it all. I've seen many solutions to execute the oposite operation but not this way.

I'm using Qt to create a temporary file. If I get its name it will be something on the likes of:

```
QTemporaryFile tempFile;
tempFile.open();
qDebug() << tempFile.fileName();
// C:/Users/USERNA~1/AppData/Local/Temp/qt_temp.Hp4264
```

I have tried some solutions such as using QFileInfo:

```
QFileInfo fileInfo(tempFile);
qDebug() << fileInfo.filePath()
```

And QDir:

```
QDir dir(tempFile.fileName());  
qDebug() << dir.absolutePath();
```

Without success.

Is there any solution for this using purely Qt? I know I can navigate the directory tree to find the full name but I was trying to avoid this, especially because of the possibility of two folders with the same prefix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the win32 function [GetLongPathName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364980%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is your answer.

```
QString shortPath = tempFile.fileName();
int length = GetLongPathNameW(shortPath.utf16(),0,0);
wchar_t* buffer = new wchar_t[length];

length = GetLongPathNameW(shortPath.utf16(), buffer, length);
QString fullpath = QString::fromUtf16(buffer, length);
delete[] buffer;
```

there is no pure Qt function for this because only windows does this (and Qt is meant to be portable)